# Bluetooth disable & visibility option greyed out

Tags: bluetooth

I have not been able to get Bluetooth to work on latest stable Freya. After many fixes, concoctions and terminal commands, the icon has since disappeared from the notification panel and clicking the bluetooth menu gives you only a toggle that does nothing else.

[image]

I have checked rfkill list, bluetooth is running okay but I cannot get it to work. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this and it worked for me, it should work for you to.

First, update your kernel to the latest long-term support:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Then, download these two firmware files:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1462614/+attachment/4453553/+files/AthrBT_0x11020100.dfu

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1462614/+attachment/4453554/+files/ramps_0x11020100_40.dfu

And put them in: `/lib/firmware/ar3k/`

Reboot, and then rejoice!